# Styles apply just to first two slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I 'm trying to do kind of slideshow on the background using two `img` tags. I have a couple of random images, so I have a javascript function to get a random name. But the main problem is: when I zoom or resize window first **two** slides crop well and display without any problem, but after that every slide is changing if I try to resize the window or zoom in-out.
Here you can see that bug: [cullycross.github.io](http://cullycross.github.io)(nevermind about big images, im gonna resize them)
Here is my code:

```
function randomBackground () {

    var active = $('#background .active');
    var next = ($('#background .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#background .active').next() : $('#background img:first');
    next.attr('src', getRandomName());

    var imgHeight = next.height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    var diff = imgHeight - windowHeight;

    if(diff > 0) {
        next.css('top', -diff*0.6);
    }

    next.css('z-index', 2);

    active.fadeOut(1500, function() {
        active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active');
        next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active');
    })
}

window.onload = function() {
    $('#background .active').attr('src', getRandomName());
    $('#background').fadeIn(1500);
    setInterval(randomBackground, 5000)
}
```

Here is css:

```
#background {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;

    overflow: hidden;
}

#background img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#background img.active {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Here is part of html:

```
<div id="background">
    <img id="current-image" class="active" />
    <img id="next-image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a url or edit the question with the code running?

Comment: @JamieHutber [link](http://cullycross.github.io) - it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found an answer, but I found a library, that makes possible that thing, that I want. Thx to https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch

Answer (score 0):

It seem to affect only the images loaded after first run. 
Try adding images directly into html, using a

```
<ul><li><img ...></li></ul>
```

structure, and get the image from there.

Comment: At first run they even don't have "src" attribute. Problem appears, when I change its value.

Answer (score 0):

You should decrease the fadeout delay. The problem is caused from the browser since the delay is big it can't handle both fadeout and zoom in/out

```
active.fadeOut(300, function() {
    active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active');
    next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active');
})
```

And try to use light size pictures, with the same aspect ratio

Comment: It doesn't work. And I talk about problem, when it's not fading in-out. Even when picture is static

Comment: @CullyCross, I found that you're using pictures with more that 500 Ko each, try to run the same code over light files, a dozen of 120 Ko each.

Comment: besides of that, talking about ratio, you're just controlling height. think about pictures of the same ratio.

Comment: I said about that in the header, first two images load well, problem of resizing starts after 2nd one.